# Module and namespace package of the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

For a Python library (say `foobar`) we currently have a module `foobar`. We now want to expand the library by offering further components (in different PyPI packages), and our preference would be to offer each component under the module name `foobar.components.component_name`.

It seems to me that namespace packages are designed to facilitate this, but I cannot figure out how.

The furthest I have gotten is by having the core package with the structure

```
foobar-core
 | pyproject.toml
 | foobar
    | __init__.py  # This contains (or imports) the core library
```

and component packages like

```
foobar-component-fizz
 | pyproject.toml
 | foobar
    | components
       | fizz.py
```

(so with `foobar` and `components` as namespace packages).

This seems to work, except that is is not possible to install the core package in the same virtual environment that is used for developing `fizz` (so with `fizz` installed as editable), which would be necessary for testing. (Once the core package is installed, the `fizz` package is not found anymore.)

Is there a way to achieve our desired module structure while preserving the ability to have the component package installed in editable mode in the same environment as the core package?

Comment: Are you looking to somehow merge foobar-component-fizz into foobar-core?

Comment: No, there supposed to stay separate packages on with separate dependencies. (A user of component ˋfizzˋ shouldn’t be forced to install all of ˋbuzzˋes dependencies.)

Answer (score 0):

It should work with package & editable version with set up sctrictly following namespacepackage requirements.

1. namespacepackage for `__init__.py`. Assuming [pkgutil-style](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkgutil-style-namespace-packages) here. In main package (foobar-core), contains ONLY
   `__path__ = __import__('pkgutil').extend_path(__path__, __name__)`
   (If there is other extras code other than this, it might work in standard package install, but probably not going to function correctly in editable mode)
2. foobar-component-fizz/foobar shall NOT have `__init__.py`
3. in setup.py add

   `from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages`
   `setup(packages=find_namespace_packages(include=["foobar.*"])`
4. Now your structure should looks something like this:

   ```
   foobar-core
    | pyproject.toml
    | setup.py
    | foobar
       | __init__.py  // __import__('pkgutil').extend_path put here


   foobar-component-fizz
    | pyproject.toml
    | setup.py. //include=["foobar.*"]
    | foobar
       | components
          | __init__.py 
          | fizz.py
   ```
5. If you'd like to have more package

   ```
   foobar-component-buzz
    | pyproject.toml
    | setup.py  // include=["foobar.*", "foobar.components.*"]
    | foobar
       | components
          | buzz
             | __init__.py 
             | buzz.py
   ```
6. Add your package dependencies in .toml file

   in foobar-component-fizz/pyproject.toml, add `dependencies = ["foobar-core"]`

   in foobar-component-buzz/pyproject.toml, add `dependencies = ["foobar-fizz"]`
7. install in editable mode. If need all in editable mode, install in chained dependency order, `pip install -e foobar-core` then `pip install -e foobar-component-fizz` finally `pip install -e foobar-component-buzz`. Otherwise just installed the dedicated subpackage in -e mode

Some spots may also worth checking but not limited to:

- clean uninstallation of packages before install. (may have uncleared `venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foobar-core/components` folder which I encountered possibly messed up during previous editing)
- worth checking **init**.py in core package and setup.py in sub-packages in detail, making sure they follows it designed to be

Comment: It seems like this does not quite work, because we need extra stuff in the core package’s \_\_init\_\_.py. (We have existing users who import it as just foobar to get access to the core parts of the library, and we don’t want to break that.) I don’t think there is another way to preserve that, right?

Comment: In this case it's bit of tricky. If there's extra stuff in core pack's __init__.py, technically not following as its designed for, so might lose the benefits that coming with the generic pkgutil. Where with that can have mixture usage of editable mode for a namespace package and normal distribution version of core package.

Comment: However, potential work around is having both core package and fizz (namespace components) both installed as editable version in your dev machine.  But before set up both editable mode, there're something worth to check:
1. if foobar-core has been installed as distribution version before in your local, worth to clean up its all namespace folder in u virtual env lib/python/site-packages/foobar (yup, i know this is not elegant). This will avoid confuse python
2. install al foobar package in order with -e (forget the order i made them work, but definitely there's depend on contents of init.py